# Encrypting files with grunt-encrypt

Tags: encryption, gruntjs

I'm trying to encrypt my .keychain files on my Mac and saving them on in a backup place. When i run `grunt enc` it just creates 2 very small files in the directory of the source files. So encrypting and moving the files doesn't go well...

package.js is just grunt with 1 devDependency grunt-encrypt.

Gruntfile.js is shown below.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var npmDependencies = require('./package.json').devDependencies;

  grunt.initConfig({
    encrypt: {
      encryptKeys: {
        options: {
          key: 'SuperSecretKey',
          dest: '/Users/myusername/www/admin/filebackup/encrypted',
        },
        files: {
            'keychains': [
              '/Library/Keychains/system.keychain', 
              '/Users/myusername/Library/Keychains/login.keychain'
            ]
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-encrypt');

  grunt.registerTask('enc', [
    'encrypt'
  ]);

};
```

I've been using Grunt for a week, so could very well be i'm missing something obvious. Anybody used grunt-encrypt before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if your SuperSecretKey is not defined yet.
I've solved it like this:
add

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
// ad here
var superSecretKey = 'secretpassword';
```

to your Gruntfile.js

Or put a keyfile (mine is called livereload.key) in the project's root and alter your Gruntfile like this:

```
//key : superSecretKey,
key: grunt.file.read('livereload.key'),
```

Comment: SuperSecretKey is the string that IS the key... It's got parentheses. It think it's supposed to work without defining it like this.